# Self-transfer at Amsterdam Schiphol airport with checked baggage

Tags: connecting-flights, ams, self-transfer

I will soon have a self-transfer at AMS, arriving from LHR on British Airways and continuing to TPE on EVA Air, both non-Schengen. I have two separate tickets.

I was initially planning to take cabin luggage only so that I can easily remain airside and walk to the next gate, but I am now thinking I might want to check my bag instead.

I found [this page](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/page/smooth-transfers/) on the Schiphol website which says:

> ...if you’re travelling on two separate tickets [...] your baggage
> will be delivered to baggage reclaim area. All you need to do is
> collect your baggage from the carousel and check it in again. For more
> information, please visit your [airline transfer desk](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/at-schiphol/services/transferdesk).

This seems to suggest that it is possible to self-transfer baggage without going through customs. However the linked page about transfer desks only talks about issuing boarding passes and sourcing tickets etc, and has no mention of baggage. Additionally, I can't find any information online about an EVA Air transfer desk.

If I were to check my bag on my British Airways flight from Heathrow, what steps would I need to take to get it checked with EVA Air?

Comment: Schiphol apparently has an app on their website where you can select date and your flights and it will give you personalized informations https://www.schiphol.nl/en/transfers/

Comment: from my link just select your BA flight, then the EVA flight

Comment: Note that you still _may be denied boarding_ at LHR if you don't have Schengen entry credentials (a visa or a visa-free passport without enough days of visa-free stay left) even if you don't have any luggage and won't be going through border controls in the Netherlands. As you have two separate tickets, worse, with two different airlines, the first company has no way of knowing for sure that you won't try entering Schengen area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I were to check my bag on my British Airways flight from Heathrow, what steps would I need to take to get it checked with EVA Air?

1. You will have to go through passport control. Make sure you have Schengen entry credentials. There is no other way to get to the baggage claim.
2. Follow the signs to baggage claim and pick up your bag
3. Exit through customs, there is no other way out of the baggage claim. You are now out of the secure area inside the Netherands.
4. Go to the EVA check in counter and check in your bags
5. Go through security
6. Head to your gate

Comment: Is the link to the airline transfer desk page a red herring then?

Comment: @user135755 No, that's just a general suggestion where to ask for more information, if you're not sure whether or not your baggage is checked through, or where to go to reclaim your bag and re-check it, etc. There's indeed no way to get into the baggage reclaim area without passing through the one-way doors from airside to landside. And those doors are from the Schengen airside concourse, so you first need to pass immigration if you're coming from outside the Schengen Area.

Comment: Also remember you need to check in before the check-in deadline, which seems to be 40 minutes before scheduled departure. If you have not checked in by then you will be considered a no-show, and your ticket is likely to be cancelled (possibly along further segments on the same ticket) and you would have to rebook and pay for z new flight at the last minute (+book and pay for a hotel, meals, transfers…). Make sure you have a **lot** of time between your flights.

Comment: @user135755: There is a  transfer desk but this is primarily for getting boarding passes, if you didn't get them during initial check in. They also help with missed connections for single-ticked itineraries. They don't deal with luggage at all.